# How do we get an "SF < 1" in the reverse recovery characteristics plot of a power diode?

Tags: diodes

The softness factor SF of a power diode is, the ratio, \$\frac{t_{b}}{t_{a}}\$.

My question is how do we get "SF < 1" when it is clearly visible in the reverse recovery characteristics of a power diode that, \$t_{b} \gt t_{a}\$ ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Consider a fraction \$\frac{n}{m}\$ where \$n>m\$, the result will *always* be greater than 1. This is also true when you fill in \$n=t_b\$ and \$m=t_a\$, getting the fraction \$\frac{t_b}{t_a}\$.

So, given a diode with \$t_b>t_a\$, the softness factor SF will *always* be greater than 1.